# jQGrid and MVC 3.0 ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

Is it possible to expose a Viewmodel's values through javascript?

The reason why i'm wondering is that my viewmodel already has all necessary data and want to bind it to a jQGrid. As i can see it i can take two approaches (probably there are more solutions i don't see):

1. Fetch data through ajax. This i have done once before in a test project and the grid displayed values. If this approach, then i suppose i wont need the viewmodel if i'm fetching data with ajax?
2. Fetch data from viewmodel. The way i have seen how you setup jQGrid is in javascript. But then, how do i get the data from viewmodel and set the jQGrid to `{ dataType: 'local', data = X }` where X should be a JSON of my viewmodel?

Hope i have made myself clear =)

I need hints to investigate further!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
return (model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

to send a Json-formatted response to your grid's get or post request.  You will need to be careful about the format the data comes in, for example we use this as a base class for all our jqGrid models:

```
public class JqGridInfo<TModel>
{
    public virtual int total { get; set; }

    public virtual int page { get; set; }

    public virtual int records { get; set; }

    public virtual List<TModel> rows { get; set; }
}
```

This will make the JSON response mimic what jqGrid expects.

Answer (score 1):

Serialize the View Model to a JSON string.  I encapsulate this behavior with a `ToJSON()` extension method.  Then you can load it as a JavaScript object with

```
 var jsObject = $.parseJSON('<%= Model.ToJSON() %>')
```

If you don't already have a JSON serialization mechanism in your solution, I highly recommend using [NewtonSoft's JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx).

It allows you to convert C# object to a JSON string representation of that object with a simple call to [`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm).